# R: Reduce factor levels (synonyms)

Tags: r, dictionary, r-factor

I'm working with an old database, that contains a lot of different codes for the same thing. In this case, I have a variable `drug` with different names for a few pharmaceutical compounds. I created a "dictionary" for all "synonyms":

```
td.codes <- list(
    [...]
    medication = list(
        acenocoumarol = c("ACENOCOUMARON", "SINTROM MITIS"),
        fenprocoumon = "MARCOUMAR",
        [...]
    )
)
```

When I read in my data, I use `factor(drug)` to create the drug variable, with all different names in it. I want to remove the specialty names and just have the generic drug name.

I figured I could do:

```
levels(drug) <- names(td.codes$medication)[sapply(levels(drugs), grep, td.codes$medication)]
```

I have troubles with the list I get from `sapply` (I'm still struggling with vapply) but even when I do `unlist(lapply(...))` I get `integer(0)` values that are not coerced to `NA` but apparently randomly assigns values to drug that are not in the dictionary.

Then I thought of first cleaning out all levels not included:

```
levels(data$drug)[which(!(levels(data$drug) %in% unlist(td.codes$medication)))] <- NA
```

and then looping over all medications in `td.codes$medication`, but I prefer something "cleaner" because the database can get really big.

My data looks like this:

```
pid   drug             [...]
  1   "ACENOCOUMARON"
  2   "MARCOUMAR"
  3   "11"
[...]
```

I googled in advance on combining factors and levels in R, but all the problems I encountered were because R did not have enough levels, instead of too many, or reducing unused levels.

Thanks in advance for your help!

EDIT

After reading [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15533594/r-factor-levels-recode-rest-to-other?rq=1) I came up with this idea:

```
factor(drug, exclude = unique(drug)[which(!(unique(drug) %in% unlist(td.codes$medication)))])
levels(drug) <- names(td.codes$medication)[unlist(sapply(levels(drug), grep, td.codes$medication))]
```

It does work, but it seems a bit verbose and inefficient.

Could you help me to improve it?

Thank you in advance!